# What is the maximum sneak damage per hit?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was wondering what the highest sneak damage you could get out of the game is, because I found some Dark Brotherhood armor, and it has a good bit of sneak damage.

Answer (score 4):

**The highest possible (passive) sneak damage multiplier you can get, is 60:**

- Sneak attacks max out at 15x damage, once the '[Assassin's Blade](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Sneak_(Skyrim)#Perks)' perk from the Sneak Perk Tree has been attained.
- Dual wielding daggers will allow your character to do a double sneak attack.
- Wearing the [Shrouded Gloves](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Shrouded_Gloves#Enchanting), sneak attack damage is doubled once more.

This results in (2 x 2 x 15x =) 60x damage.

This can be increased using active powers:

- As an Orc, you have the racial ability [Berserker Rage](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Orsimer_(Skyrim)#Character_creation), which doubles your damage as well (for 60 seconds. Combined with the other factors, this results in a multiplier of **120**).
- The [Marked for Death](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marked_for_Death#Notes) shout damages armor ratings up to 75 points per second: it effectively adds damage multipliers if the enemy's armor rating drops below 0 and into negative numbers.

Comment: It's unlikely for an enemy to calm down enough to do a sneak attack after a mark of death. I guess you can forcefully calm them after.

Comment: To be fair, if you have the shadow warrior perk, you can literally sneak attack during active combat by just quickly crouching and timing your attack well (you have about a half second window for it to reliably register as a sneak attack)

Comment: Daggers count as One-Handed weapons for the Armsman perk in the One-Handed skill tree, giving up to 100% extra one handed weapon damage. Does this stack with the other effects listed?

Comment: @Andrew I assume it will.